# Show Data database only with specific ID

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I have this code to show all data in my database:

```
<?php foreach($alldatas as $data): ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="content">
                <h3><?php echo $data['data_name'];?></h3>
                <div class="footer text-center">
                <?php echo $data['data_version'];?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

That code works perfect to show all my data with different `data_name` and `data_version`. But what I want is to show the data only with specific ID.

So I want to make it work with bootstrap navtabs:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#pro" aria-controls="pro" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Pro</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#middle" aria-controls="middle" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Middle</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#low" aria-controls="low" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Low</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<?php foreach($alldatas as $data): ?>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="pro">
            <?php if($data['id'] == "2" | $data['id'] == "3" | $data['id'] == "4"){?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3><?php echo $data['data_name'];?></h3>
                            <div class="footer text-center">
                            <?php echo $data['data_version'];?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="middle">
            <?php if($data['id'] == "5" | $data['id'] == "6" | $data['id'] == "7"){?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3><?php echo $data['data_name'];?></h3>
                            <div class="footer text-center">
                            <?php echo $data['data_version'];?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But it just only show data with ID 1,2,3 when I try to click other tabs. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having foreach loop on "tab-content" which is wrong, actually, it will create so many "tab-content"s and that's not required. You **MUST** loop for content not "tab-content".

So, first fix would be:

```
 <div class="tab-content">

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="pro">
        <?php foreach($alldatas as $data): ?>
            <?php if($data['id'] == "2" | $data['id'] == "3" | $data['id'] == "4"){?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3><?php echo $data['data_name'];?></h3>
                            <div class="footer text-center">
                                <?php echo $data['data_version'];?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="middle">
        <?php foreach($alldatas as $data): ?>
            <?php if($data['id'] == "5" | $data['id'] == "6" | $data['id'] == "7"){?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3><?php echo $data['data_name'];?></h3>
                            <div class="footer text-center">
                                <?php echo $data['data_version'];?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

It will resolve your issue, however, if it still persists, you can implement a jquery function for custom toggling of "active" class. (Still, first correct the position of "foreach" as shown above).

Comment: Glad to hear that!